# Add temporary column with number in sequence in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two columns: **customers** and **orders**. orders has `customer_id` column. So customer can have many orders. I need to find order number in sequence (by date). So result should be something like this:

```
customer_id  order_date  number_in_sequence
-----------  ----------  ------------------
1            2020-01-01  1
1            2020-01-02  2
1            2020-01-03  3
2            2019-01-01  1
2            2019-01-02  2
```

I am going to use it in [WITH clause](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-with-clause/). So I don't need to add it to the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `row_number()` :

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by order_date) as number_in_sequence
from table t;
```

Comment: awesome! exactly what I was looking for. thanks. will accept your answer in 10 mins :)